# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in UIApplicationMain

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access

I am getting this error in line:

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're sending a message to a memory address of an already released object, most likely.

Such memory problems don't always show up at the point that the error occurred.

Have a look at turning on NSZombies as a first step towards finding the problem.